# Cruce de dos tablas por fecha más cercana con BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Estoy trabajando en *BigQuery* hace poco y quiero unir dos tablas por la fecha mas cercana, la tabla A tiene datos diarios; mientras que la tabla B tiene identificador cada x tiempo. Deseo unir estas tablas.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comparto una muestra de datos:

**Tabla A**

| Q | X | Y | Z | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | a2 | b2 | c2 | 2021-01-01 |
| 10 | a1 | b1 | c1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 20 | a1 | b1 | c2 | 1010-02-02 |
| 40 | a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-04-03 |
| 10 | a1 | b1 | c2 | 2020-06-02 |
| 60 | a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-09-03 |

**Tabla B**

| X | Y | Z | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b8 | c1 | 2021-01-01 | 1000 |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | 2020-01-01 | 1100 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 | 1010-02-02 | 500 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 | 2020-04-03 | 800 |
| a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-06-02 | 700 |
| a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-09-03 | 1000 |

**Result**

| Q | X | Y | Z | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | a2 | b2 | c2 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| 10 | a1 | b1 | c1 | 2020-01-01 | 1100 |
| 20 | a1 | b1 | c2 | 1010-02-02 | 500 |
| 40 | a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-04-03 | 700 |
| 10 | a1 | b1 | c2 | 2020-06-02 | 800 |
| 60 | a1 | b2 | c3 | 2020-09-03 | 1000 |

Es importante siempre tener tabla A completa.

Muchas Gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá no sea del todo correcta, pues es la primera irrupción que tengo en BigQuery, pero la [sintaxis](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) para esto según la doc, es un left join, lo que corresponde a todas las filas del conjunto que está a la izquierda (a) y todas las de la derecha que existan para la relación.

```
Select a.*, b.price 
From a LEFT JOIN B on a.x = b.x and a.y = b.y and a.z = b.z;
```